# Paste mode / multi-line-snippet in the kotlin REPL?

Tags: kotlin, paste, read-eval-print-loop

Given the skeleton of a function:

```
fun reformat(
    str: String,
    normalizeCase: Boolean = true,
    upperCaseFirstLetter: Boolean = true,
    divideByCamelHumps: Boolean = false,
    wordSeparator: Char = ' ',
) {
  println("In reformat")
}
```

I pasted this into the kotlin REPL and it complained - clearly due to not realizing it were being sent a multi-line snippet:

```
>>> fun reformat(
error: parameter name expected
fun reformat(
             ^
error: expecting comma or ')'
fun reformat(
             ^
error: expecting ')'
fun reformat(
             ^

>>>     str: String,
error: expecting an element
    str: String,
       ^
error: expecting an element
    str: String,
               ^

etc ..
```

What is the equivalent of the `:paste` in the scala REPL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a project - **apparently actively improved by the JetBrains kotlin developers themselves** that addresses this and other issues: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-interactive-shell .  Here is their help

```
[0] :h
:quit or q                           quit the shell
:load or l <path>                    load file and evaluate
:type or t <expr>                    display the type of an expression without evaluating it
:list or ls                          list defined symbols
:help or h [command]                 print this summary or command-specific help
:paste or p                          enter paste mode
:syntax {on | off}                   syntax highlighting
:prompt [pattern]                    customize prompt
:set                                 set configuration parameter
:conf                                list configuration parameters
:dependsOn <artifact coordinates>    Load dependency from the current set of repositories
:repository <repository coordinates> Add repository for the artifacts lookup
:classpath or cp                     Show current script compilation classpath
```

Notice in particular :

```
[1] :p
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
```

That is precisely what I am looking for. It does work (though with ugly JDK9 warnings):

```
[1] :p
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
fun reformat(
    str: String,
    normalizeCase: Boolean = true,
    upperCaseFirstLetter: Boolean = true,
    divideByCamelHumps: Boolean = false,
    wordSeparator: Char = ' ',
) {
  println("In reformat")
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil (file:/Users/steve/git/kotlin-interactive-shell/ki-shell/target/ki-shell-0.4-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar) to method java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[2] reformat()
ERROR No value passed for parameter 'str' (Line_3.kts:1:10)
[3] reformat("abc")
In reformat
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Kotlin REPL is intended to be used from the IDE. If you open it from within Intellij IDEA, it works like a charm and allows you multiline input. I don't see any options which allow you to do the same from the regular shell. So, in your case, you can either declare a function in one line or load the script from a file.

Comment: wow that's a bummer. I'm a JetBrains fanatic (since 2008) but sometimes I just don't want the overhead of opening the IDE even for python (vs Pycharm) or scala (vs IJ)